# Removing characters if string is larger than 255 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I want to Remove string Characters if string is more than varchar(255) length and save that in database in c#

I am not able to find any solution .

```
string test.RatingItemName="hshhhdhhdshdsdsddssdsdsghdsh";

if (test.RatingItemName > varchar(255))
{
    //trim the extra characters after varchar(255)
}
```

Comment: If you try and save a string longer than 255 characters to a varchar(255) then it will get truncated anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `substring`. Try like:

```
string test.RatingItemName="hshhhdhhdshdsdsddssdsdsghdsh";
if(test.RatingItemName.Length>255)
{
   test = test.RatingItemName.Substring(0,255);
}
```